# Two types of invoice numbering (2 tables with 0..1 relationship)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

I have table invoices - PK is year+document_type_id+number (this is current numbering, and i can't change it). So, the data is like this:

```
year    document_type_id   number
2013    351                1  
2013    351                2
2013    352                1
```

Now, i need to develop second type of numbering - table invoices_2 - PK is year+market_id+cash_register_id+number (this is numbering for some of invoices which is proscribed by the law), and FK is invoices_year+invoices_document_type_id+invoices_number.

invoice - invoice_2 must be 1 -> 0..1 relationship.

The problem is that in invoices_2 table i may have this (which i would like to eliminate - using some PK+FK combination?):

```
year  market_id  cash_register_id  number  invoices_year inovices_document_type invoices_number
2013     1              1            1         2013           351                    1
2013     1              1            2         2013           351                    1
```

As you can see, the invoice 2013-351-1 using  can be added more that 1 times in invoices_2 table, which must be forbidden.

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b42c/1

Comment: Create Unique constraint on `invoices_2(invoices_year inovices_document_type invoices_number)`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to put the second numbering system in its own table.

```
Invoice
-------
year
document_type_id
number
invoice_2_fk
...


Invoice_2
---------
invoice_2 _id
year
market_id
cash_register_id
number
```

The invoice 2 foreign key in the Invoice table is nullable.  When it's null, there is no invoice 2.  When it's a valid id, then there is an invoice 2.  This is a one to zero / one relationship.